# How to see health of instances in a load balancer?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-resource-manager

I have configured a load balancer and some VMs using an Azure Resource Manager Template. Everything seems to be in order, but I cannot find a way to view the 'health' of the instances in the load balancer in the console, or with the xplat command line tool.

In AWS it's really easy to go to the console, find an Elastic Load Balancer, and view the instances attached, and if they're InService or OutOfService.

Is there any way to query the instance status in Azure? I've tried searching MSDN, the Azure command line tool commands for load balancing and the Portal (I'm using Resource Manager, so can't use manage., but had this problem with the Service Management API too).

Answer (score 0):

Azure is the responsible of dealing with the health of the load balancers. You don't need to worry about it, Azure Fabric will monitor it's status and deal with possible failures thanks to its high-availabity design.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my question that it's the instance health I'm after. I have edited the question slightly.

Comment: With Management Services you can monitor web endpoint status -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn306639.aspx but in ARM I think there is nothing similar yet.